# how to install sql server 2014/windows 7 so that I allow a windows 10 user to connect to it

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking, sql-server-2014

At my home, I have 2 PCs from our client company (I don't have better windows images and I would prefer not changing them, at least the windows 10 image/PC):

| PC | Windows | SQL server | SSMS | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7, version 6.1, build 7601 sp1 | 2014 (installation in progress) | not yet | 192.168.0.10 |
| 2 | 10, version1803, build17134.345 | 2017 | 18.1 | 192.168.0.105 |

**The final goal:** to have the PC1 act as a sql server and PC2 as a client (that can access the server's dbs). **Update1:** I want an application from PC2 to be able to change data from the PC1's db.

**The problem:** I don't know what the username/PC/workgroup should look like in the Database Engine Configuration screen (especially in the SQL Server administration section). I had tried the followings:

- WORKGROUP\(PC2 username) I get: an object cannot be found
- (PC2Name)\(PC2 username) I get: an object cannot be found
- \\(PC2Name)\(PC2 username) I get: the following name is not valid... To specify an object on a computer,  use the following format: computer\item. To specify a computer, use the following format: \\computer
  **UPDATE1:** Would this (addition of a user from PC2) suffice in order to allow applications from PC2 to change data on PC1?

[image]

Q: Why are the machines so different? A: That's all I get for the moment from our client company. (I'm trying to access the inferior with something superior, which I believe/hope it should work)

As side notes:

1. although I have the file and printer sharing started on both machines, when ping-ing the PC2 from PC1 I get "Reply from 192.168.0.10: Destination host unreachable" - I don't know how/if this will influence the ability for the PC2 to connect to PC1.
2. both PCs are in the same workgroup (right click on PC > Properties);
3. on both PCs I had shared some folders and I can see them from the other PC;
4. these 2 PCs are in a separate network at my home (they are both connected only to a router, which is not connected to internet)

Thank you!
R

Comment: A few things to check in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Are the SQL services running? Under client protocols, are TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled? Is the TCP/IP port set to 1433? Do you have any firewalls turned on? Is the instance named? i.e. did you call it hostname\SQL2k16? Or did you not specify an instance name?

Comment: @spikey_richie on PC1 I hadn't finished the installation

Comment: @spikey_richie on PC2, the SQL Server Agent wasn't running, and I started it

Comment: @spikey_richie on PC2, the TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled (both in SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 bit) and in SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration)

Comment: @spikey_richie - the Default Port is set to 1433 (in both of the above locations)

Comment: @spikey_richie - (on both machines) I have only the default Windows firewalls settings

Comment: @spikey_richie - the instance is named the same for both PCs (it doesn't include any hostname)

Comment: @spikey_richie on PC1, after restarting SQL Server Agent from PC2, I'd tried again to add the user from the PC2, and I get the same thing - on object named ... cannot be found